# Merge/ Synonym request [xcode-playground] and [swift-playground]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[xcode-playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-playground) has 22 questions and [swift-playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-playground) has 10 questions. They refer to the same thing. Can we merge them?

Comment: Which one is the master?

Comment: I'd choose xcode-playground. It's more popular and I like it more, but I guess that could be up for discussion.

Comment: Does the playground work with Objective C, or only with Swift?

Comment: only with swift

Comment: It's the swift playground then.  See http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=swift+playground&word2=xcode+playground

Comment: works for me. Just seemed silly having two tags